# Stream iPad audio to other devices?

Tags: ipad, vlc

I used to stream a music from my desktop to wdtv using VLC.

I would like to stream all the sound from my iPad to wdtv.

I googled about it, but I only found how to stream music from other devices to iPad.

Comment: What is WDTV? An app, or actual TV?

Comment: @VjJaonxV // It is a external multimedia player. The point of my question is how to make a stream server in ipad.

Comment: A stream server is all well and good, but knowing what WDTV is dictates what it can connect to and what formats is important. There are solutions such as http://appshopper.com/utilities/streamtome , but they require you to run software on a computer in order to work, and probably doesn't work on WDTV...

Comment: @VxJasonxV//thanks you for your input. As you wrote, streamtome requires a desktop, which is what I am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to hook up an Airport Express with audio cables to your external multimedia player, or Apple TV. Then you can stream iTunes directly to either of these devices - the functionality is built-in to iOS 4 and works awesome!